# Assigning variable length arrays to 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to assign variables length arrays to a 2D NumPy array, at a variable starting index (offset).
I've managed by using a loop but I wonder to know if there is a smarter way for example using iterators, vectorization or other methods.

Here the code example:

```
>>> rd
array([array([-35., -31., -27., -23., -19., -14., -10.,  -5.]),
       array([-24., -21., -18., -15., -11.,  -8.,  -4.]),
       array([-7., -6., -4., -2.]),
       array([-16., -13., -11.,  -8.,  -6.,  -3.])], dtype=object)
>>> offset = np.array([2,3,0,1])
>>> res = np.zeros((offset.size,10))
>>> for i in range(offset.size) :
...     res[i, offset[i]:offset[i]+rd[i].size] = rd[i] 
... 
>>> res
array([[  0.,   0., -35., -31., -27., -23., -19., -14., -10.,  -5.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0., -24., -21., -18., -15., -11.,  -8.,  -4.],
       [ -7.,  -6.,  -4.,  -2.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0., -16., -13., -11.,  -8.,  -6.,  -3.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])
>>>
```

`rd` has filled `res` matrix with the correct offset.
But, is there a way to get the same result avoiding the for loop in order to speed up the execution?

Comment: Show some of the results along the way.  I can't run the code in my head, and prefer not to run the whole script on my computer.

Comment: You might also want to simplify the code sample to focus on what really matters.  For example do you really need the `dataframe` and ` `npf` calculations?  Is that last loop the focus of your question?

Comment: @hpaulj, thanks for the comment. Yes, the last loop is the focus of my question.

Comment: Looks like an array padding question.  That's been discussed a number of times in the past.  The simplest to explain is `itertools.zip_longest`.  There's a fancier method developed by Divakar, but it's harder to explain and cite offhand.